# Navbar Disappear after sometimes for no reason on mobile width

Tags: html, css, sass

so when i first open the navbar on mobile width its stay on perfectly but after few time 15-20sec the navbar disappear for some reason but the .open class stay on css property after few time playing with inspect element find out something going on with z-index property when increase the property manually from inspect element it comeback again so why this happening if something wrong with it shouldn't be appear in the first place why this work and suddenly not

here's my code:
`

```
.open{
     display: flex !important;
 }
 .navbar .flex ul{
    flex-direction: column;
    background: $primary-color;
    position:absolute;
    top:63px;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 18px;
    border-radius: 5px;
    display: none;
    z-index:2;
    border-bottom:1px solid $secondary-text;
    transition:transform .6s ease-in-out;
    animation:slide 12s ease 15s;
    li:hover{
        border-bottom: 1px solid $text-color;
    }
    li a{
        color:$text-color;
    }
 }
```

`

Comment: Hi Can you add your HTML code as well? And make sure there's a enough code there that replicates the problem.

Comment: did you try "position absolute" for ".open" and set z-index for that?
please add more code, like your HTML or if use JS.

Comment: and what does the animation called 'slide' do?